# Wiki with prioritized keyword indexing (tags)

Tags: search, wiki

We need an in-house wiki for a technical piece of software. The problem we're having is finding information. Full text searches fail miserably, finding 1,000 pages when only 10 are relevant and never in priority. Tags are barely better as we can have 100 entries marked 'EMV', but 5 are specifically on the topic, and the others are relevant to the term, but low priority.

I want to allow users to provide a set of tags from a predefined list, and **assign them a priority** so that people searching (1) can see a list of all available tags and (2) when searching for a tag, get results listed in priority.

Everything out there assumes that you cannot trust users to do a decent job indexing/tagging, which may be right. However, we know for sure that computer attempts fail miserably, so I am reduced to depending on humans :-).

Is there any wiki software that supports this sort of tagging? My needs are small (small group, even a personal wiki if necessary).

Comment: Try [Tiddlywiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/). Tagging is easy and there are other ways to slice and dice.

Comment: I've been trying TiddlyWiki and like what I see, but it allows a tag to have a list of tiddlers that it will output in order first, which is useful for the "this page must appear before this page" for a given tag.  But it doesn't seem to support just assigning a relevance rating of some sort. However, there are a lot of plug-ins, and I'm checking those out.